# My test indicates .NET Remoting is faster than WCF 4 by a factor of 1.5

Tags: wcf, performance, comparison, remoting, .net-remoting

In order to tell whether my project should migrate from .net remoting to WCF, I extracted its network communication part and implemented it by WCF. I run the remoting version and wcf version and eventually find **remoting is faster than wcf by a factor of 1.5**, which greatly differs from [the msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx#wcfperform_topic3d).

## Test configuration

WCF and .NET Remoting both use tcp channel without encryption, no app.config file. Compiled in release mode, no optimization.

## Operations

What my program does is this.
[image: sequence diagram]

[**You can download the two solutions here.**](http://www.box.com/s/lai03ktzdi0gzo5tlv63)

### WCF test

Service Host

```
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Server), new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", args[0], args[1], args[2])));
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 614400;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 512000;//a max picture of 500KB
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServer), binding, string.Empty);
    host.Open();
```

Server

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single
    //, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
    , ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant
    )]
public class Server : IServer
{
    public EntryRequirement GetEntryRequirement()
    {
        return new EntryRequirement(new[] { "fuck", "sex" }, false);
    }

    public void AddClient()
    {
        var client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServerCallback>();
        var p = client.Profile;
        var x = client.Password;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Client side

```
    Player player = new Player();
    player.Password = "12423";
    player.Profile = new Contracts.PlayerProfile
                         {
                             Description = "I'm a man.",
                             HeadImage = imageData,
                             Name = "Loveright"
                         };


    var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        ServerProxy server = new ServerProxy(player, binding, 
            new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", args[0], args[1], args[2])));
        server.GetEntryRequirement();
        server.AddClient();
    }

    watch.Stop();
```

HeadImage is a picture of size 139KB.

Player class

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
class Player : IServerCallback
{
    public PlayerProfile Profile { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public void ClientCollectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, ControllersChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void ClientUpdatedEventHandler(object sender, ClientUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

### .NET Remoting test

Host

```
    var serverProv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
    serverProv.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
    var clientProv = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
    IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
    props["port"] = args[1];
    props["name"] = "tcp server";
    var channel = new TcpChannel(props, clientProv, serverProv);

    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

    System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(Server),
                                args[2], System.Runtime.Remoting.WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

Client

```
    var serverProv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
    serverProv.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
    var clientProv = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
    IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
    props["name"] = "tcp client " + Guid.NewGuid();
    props["port"] = 0;

    var channel = new TcpChannel(props, clientProv, serverProv);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

    FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"logotz6.png", FileMode.Open);
    byte[] imageData = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    stream.Close();
    Player player = new Player();
    player.Password = "12423";
    player.Profile = new PlayerProfile
    {
        Description = "I'm a man.",
        HeadImage = imageData,
        Name = "Loveright"
    };

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var serverProxy = (IServer)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IServer), string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", args[0], args[1], args[2]));
        serverProxy.GetEntryRequirement();
        serverProxy.AddClient(player);
    }
    watch.Stop();
```

[You can download the two solutions here.](http://www.box.com/s/lai03ktzdi0gzo5tlv63)

## Result

[image]

**So do I make the test somewhere unfair to WCF?**

Comment: Remoting is deprecated. That is the biggest reason for getting your application on an uplift schedule - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Anyway. Remoting is fast and WCF has some limitations that remoting doesn't have. Now one of my application is using remoting.

Comment: Until I can squeeze the same performance out of WCF, I will also continue to keep .net Remoting in my toolbox.

Comment: Was it Debug or Release bulid? In this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056809/694852) the Release build seems to fix the issue.

Comment: "Compiled in release mode"

Answer (score 0):

Should it be the message encoding king ?

Have you used binaryMessageEncoding instead of textMessageEncoding or soapMessageEncoding ?

You can create a custom binding to do this :

```
internal sealed class MyBinding : CustomBinding
{
    private static readonly BindingElementCollection elementCollection;

    static MyBinding()
    {
        MessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();

        TcpTransportBindingElement transport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();

        elementCollection = new BindingElementCollection();
        elementCollection.Add(encoding);
        elementCollection.Add(transport);
    }

    internal MyBinding(string bindingName, string bindingNamespace)
        : base()
    {
        base.Namespace = bindingNamespace;
        base.Name = bindingName;
    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        return elementCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you find I'm using textMessageEncoding or soapMessageEncoding?

Comment: You can create a custom binding (by extending the class CustomBinding (System.ServiceModel.Channels)).